# Showing the active link in php using bootstrap universal navigation bar

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I am creating a website in php and bootstrap 4.I included  a universal navigation bar and the called it with the `<?php include 'filename.php'?>`. How do I show the active link on each of the pages for example if its on the `index.html`,the home button or link will be highlighted.

Comment: Found the solution to this in php.It's easy.Just use,`<li class="nav-item <?php if($page=='pagename'){echo 'active';}?>">
              <a class="nav-link" href="pagename.php">Home</a>`
            </li>
Then include the navbar file and create a variable with page and assign it to the pagename you set for example for home use,

`<?php $page='home'; include 'header.php';?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript for showing the current active url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location;
        $('ul.nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
        $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
             return this.href == url;
        }).parent().addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```